# Apply for a Secret CIA Job

Tags: cipher

The **CIA** are hiring cryptographers of three levels, just solve your corresponding rank's cipher to apply for the job.

**Basic cryptographer:**

> "We are sure he/her in neglected greatness, triumphs over nefariousness."
>   -Doctor Cryptology
>
> -post your job application in the "cmbdl mfuufscpy"

**Lead cryptologist:**

> The Key for this AutoKey Cipher Is "lartneCecnegilletnIycnegA"
>
> yiyeuoym, lhyc cmghl vs juma wq, zideucl itslpkliqe, tzu sdvxwqgw rfi czzv vvbzbrj, ayo lzig xb piu mivf.

**Covert Mastermind:**

> Try and Crack the CIA's own Master Code:
>
> Xdmbplf sp sid odx zhd, xd'wd cdfm nphunshof znv epq zdbqt, rudq nvsthed,
>    xdmbplf sp sid DHB.

Hints **(WE KNOW IF YOU USE THEM)**:

**Basic Cryptographer:**

> Pay Attention to the starting letters

**Lead Cryptologist:**

> It's an AutoKey Cipher

**Covert Mastermind:**

> Pay attention to the letters that come before and after the current one in the alphabet

- For Your Eyes Only

***CLASSIFIED INFO***

Comment: that is much better. remember the use of ">!" at the beggining of a line to hide it. (I edit for you to see)

Comment: seem so. see the difference between your previous post and this one? good job

Comment: @StackOverflow-Are you sure _Lead cryptologist_ text is valid?

Comment: Fixed the Cipher Text In Lead Cryptographer!

Comment: Ok, A suggestion- Always try to double check your puzzle before posting it. That ciphertext was unsolvable initially.

Comment: @Sid Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Partial**

For Basic cryptographer:

> The answer is already posted by @Sid
>  Initial letters give WASHINGTON DC and the code with a rot 25 gives Black Letterbox

For Lead Cryptologist:

> The key is actually "CentralIntelligenceAgency" (CIA) spelled backwards

The message is

> Well done, your ready to join us, destroy everything, all evidence you ever existed, and head to New York

For the Covert Mastermind:

> The odd letters are ROT25 (shifted left by 1) and the even ones are ROT1 (shifted right by 1)

so the message is:

> Welcome to the new age, we've been **monitoring** you for years, step outside, welcome to the CIA

Comment: mqgvmtgpe, each letter rotates out. so "m" couldn't be in there, but thanks anyway, I'll check over it

Comment: Oh you already got it, didn't notice :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan oh, thanks, good job on getting the Covert Mastermind one done too:)

Comment: Have you tried doing the cipher text backward?

Comment: Fixed the Cipher Text should be finish-able now.

Comment: You Did It! Good Job, your now a member of the CIA!

Comment: How come the CIA cannot manage basic grammar?

Answer (score 4):

Partial(Working)

**-post your job application in the "cmbdl mfuufscpy"**

> Rot 25 gives Black LetterBox which gives -post your job application in the **"Black Letter Box"**

Answer (score 3):

The basic cryptographer

> Initial letters give WASHINGTON D.C. (Pointed out by @JonathanAllan) and the code with a rot 25 gives Black Letter Box

The covert Mastermind

> As oleslaw finds out (Which I also did find independently, except the "monitoring" part, which I was a bit confused on), it is "Welcome to the new age, we've been monitoring you for years, step outside, welcome to the CIA"

The lead Cryptologist

> It is an autokey cipher with the key as "CENTRALINTELLIGENCEAGENCY" (as @Oleslaw found out). Solving it, we get :"welldone, your ready to join us, destroy everything, all evidence you ever existed, and head to new york."

Comment: ... **D**octor **C**ryptology.

Answer (score 3):

Lead is what it says on the tin:

> key-autokey with just the reversed words reversed and lower cased: `centralintelligenceagency`
>  yields:
>  `welldone, your ready to join us, destroy everything, all evidence you ever existed, and head to new york.`

Covert:

> Rotate back 1 letter or forward one letter alphabetically:
>  `Wclaoke ro rhc ncw ygc, wc'vc bcel mogtmrgne ymu dop ycaps, qtcp mursgdc, wclaoke ro rhc CGA`
>  `Yencqmg tq tje pey aie, ye'xe degn oqivotipg aow fqr aecru, sver owtuife, yencqmg tq tje EIC`
>  and interleave:
>  `Welcome to the new age, we've been mqitoring you for years, step outside, welcome to the CIA`
>  pretty sure `mqitoring` is meant to be `monitoring`.

...and for completeness basic:

> Reading the first line as an acrostic yields `Washington D.C.`
>  and rotate the letters of the quoted text back one alphabetically to yield `black letterbox`

Comment: correct, but I don't know how you ended up with mqitoring?

Comment: Oh, I saw it was wrong and worked from the back of the word the `m` start seemed likely with the result, maybe I should say `ooitoring` though.

Comment: @StackOverflow by the way I don't think they would use `your` where `you're` would be correct; nice little puzzle though.